# How to validate that fromDate and toDate both exist or absent in get request with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I have Get request

```
localhost:8080/company/{id}/resource?fromDate=2020-12-03T18:01:00Z&toDate=2020-12-03T18:12:00Z
```

In this request fromDate and toDate are optional, so basically I can call

```
localhost:8080/company/{id}/resource
```

And it will return response for me.

Now I want to validate in correct way that both fromDate and toDate were passed or neither of thme were passed.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/company/{id}/resource")
public String getParameterOverride(
@PathVariable String id,
@RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) ZonedDateTime fromDate,
@RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) ZonedDateTime toDate
) {
    // check dates logic
     return id;
}
```

The problem is that I don't want to write something like

```
if(fromDate == null && toDate == null) {
 ...
}
```

I'm using Spring Boot. Is there any other way to validate this fields? My idea was to create new POJO and then validate them there, but I didn't manage to figure out how to do it. How to check that both fileds are present in POJO or vise versa? And also From Date is before to Date?

Comment: How do you want to validate fields if you refuse to do null checks?

Comment: @f1sh I want to validate fields set into POJO, I'm not refusing of doing it

Comment: Then set it into a pojo, what is the problem? Then you have to do the null checks in the pojo's method. What do you expect to gain from that?

Comment: If you don't like the syntax, you can use `Objects.isNull(obj)` instead @BohdanMyslyvchuk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found solution which I was seeking for.

Just to check this two parameters in if statement was very straightforward approach which I believe is not reusable.

I found out that you can map you request params fields by name directly into POJO. Then using validation you can create constraint which will check two dependent fields for any condition you like.

Lets say you have request

```
http://localhost:8080/myresource?dateFrom=2020-01-01&dateTo=2020-01-02
```

Then you controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/myresource")
public String getMyResource(@Valid DateRangePojo dateRangePojo ) {
    return null;
}
```

My question was "how to validate that you have both dateFrom and dateTo or neither of them".

Then Pojo

```
@Data
@CheckDateRange
public class DateRangePojo {

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private final ZonedDateTime dateFrom;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private final ZonedDateTime dateTo;
}
```

@CheckDateRange- is custom annotation to check if present both dates.

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CheckDatesValidator.class)
public @interface CheckDateRange{

    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}

public class CheckDatesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CheckDateRange, DateRangePojo> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final DateRangePojo value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
   // your logic to check if valid
    }
  }
```

Every time when new request comes it will be validate by isValid method.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare them with `Optional` if the request param is optional

```
@RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) Optional<ZonedDateTime> fromDate,
@RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) Optional<ZonedDateTime> toDate
```

And then in code you don't need multiple checks, `Optional.map` will only get executed if `Optional` is not empty

```
if(fromDate.isPresent() && toDate.isPresent()) {
     return //value
  }

 fromDate.map(/*call method*/).orElseGet(()-> toDate.map(/*call method*/).orElse(/*default value*/));
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, but what benefit will I get? How can I validate that for example toDate was passed and fromDate not and throw exception? Or should I check every param?

Comment: i did updated the code how to use optional and advantage of it @BohdanMyslyvchuk

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Valid` annotation to check if the datatype is valid like very basic one

```
@GetMapping(value = "/company/{id}/resource")
public String getParameterOverride(
@PathVariable String id,
@RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) @Valid ZonedDateTime fromDate,
@RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) @Valid ZonedDateTime toDate
) {
    // check dates logic
     return id;
}
```

For a more customized one, you can look for `ConstraintValidator`

Comment: thanks for your comment. Ok fromDate was passed and it is valid. But I can run service method only with both params. How to notify that one missing?

Comment: There are no out-of-box annotation to send you an error for missing parameters, you have to use ControllerAdvice.